# Alert angular confirm

Tags: html, angularjs

Supongamos que en mi controlador tengo:

```
var confirm = true;
```

y en mi html:

```html
    <a href="index" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Index</a>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que :

- si la variable "confirm" es true salga un mensaje diciendo ¿seguro que desea volver?, si le da a si vuelve y si le da a no permanece
- si la variable "confirm" es false directamente redirija

NOTA: no me gustaría pasar por el controlador para hacer esta comprobación

Answer (score 1):

He entendido dos cosas diferentes:

**1:** El `<a>` depende de la variable `confirm`.

**2:** La accion depende del resultado del `confirm`.

---

**1:**
Primero declara confirmar usando `$scope`.
Despues condiciona la aparición del `<a>` utilizando la propiedad `ng-if`.
De esta manera podras ver que si confirmar es falso no se muestro, y si es true si.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.confirmar = true;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <a href="index" ng-if='confirmar' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Index</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

**2:**

Tratar el true o false mediante una función y ejecutar el resultado deseado. No he puesto lo de las redirecciones porque no se que quieres poner exactamente.

```js
function confirmar(){
var r = confirm("¿seguro que desea volver?");
if (r == true) {
    alert("\'codgio de vuelta (true)\'");
} else {
    alert("\'codgio de redireccion (false)\'");
}
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return confirmar();">Index</a>
```

Comment: es una solucion, pero para que funcione tendria que tener 2 <a href> porque si confirmar es falso no deberia salirme el alert pero si el link, estaba buscando sin tener 2 href

Comment: echale un ojo a la segunda opcion que he puesto.